# Web-scraping a table

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the table value in this link [https://www.cellmapper.net/arfcn?net=LTE&ARFCN=78&MCC=0](https://www.cellmapper.net/arfcn?net=LTE&ARFCN=78&MCC=0/). Every time I need to change the net type (LTE or 3G or 2G) then I will change the ARFCN value and I want to get the "Band Number" from the table result. I can't read all data of the result table by this code.

My code:

```
from lxml.html import parse
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def htmltodf(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,features="lxml")
    tables = soup.findAll('table')
    test = pd.io.html.read_html(str(tables))
    print(test)

htmltodf("https://www.cellmapper.net/arfcn?net=LTE&ARFCN=78&MCC=0")
```

The result I get: all is NAN

```
[                                       Result  Result.1
0                                Network Type       NaN 
1                                   E/U/ARFCN       NaN 
2                                   Band Name       NaN 
3    Uplink Frequency (phone to base station)       NaN 
4  Downlink Frequency (base station to phone)       NaN 
5                                 **Band Number       NaN** 
6                         Possible Bandwidths       NaN 
7                                Sector Color       NaN]
```

Comment: You have to use another url to get data because your current page is just an empty template. Data are dynamically loaded when you click on button 'Calculate'

Answer (score 1):

Try this version:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from itertools import product

url = 'https://api.cellmapper.net/v6/getFrequency'
channel = [70, 71]
rat = ['LTE', 'UMTS', 'GSM']

data = {}
for vals in product(channel, rat):
    payload = dict(zip(['Channel', 'RAT'], vals))
    r = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
    if r['statusCode'] == 'OKAY':
        sr = pd.Series(r['responseData'])
        data[vals] = sr
df = pd.concat(data, names=['Channel', 'RAT'], axis=1).T.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Channel  RAT netType Frequency startFrequencyDLNumber endFrequencyDLNumber bandName bandNumber rxFrequency txFrequency modulation region MCC possibleBandwidth
0       70  LTE     LTE        70                      1                  599      IMT          1      1927.0      2117.0        FDD  WORLD   0   [5, 10, 15, 20]
1       70  GSM     GSM        70                      0                  124  GSM 900        900       904.0       949.0       TDMA  WORLD   0             [0.2]
2       71  LTE     LTE        71                      1                  599      IMT          1      1927.1      2117.1        FDD  WORLD   0   [5, 10, 15, 20]
3       71  GSM     GSM        71                      0                  124  GSM 900        900       904.2       949.2       TDMA  WORLD   0             [0.2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider taking a look at this.

https://www.cellmapper.net/TOS

Cellmapper is a community driven project, please don't abuse it.